# docker compose a few env files and args section

Tags: docker-compose

Here's the example of `docker-compose.yml` file which contains a service and has defined two files as the `env_file`

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  admin:
    ...
    build:
      context: .
      ...
      args:
        - SSH_USER=$SSH_USER
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .env.local
...
```

The content of `.env` file is:

```
SSH_USER="change-me"
```

The content of `.env.local` file is:

```
SSH_USER="change-me2"
```

Here's the result of `docker compose config` command:

```
services:
  admin:
    build:
      ...
      args:
        SSH_USER: change-me
    ...
    environment:
      SSH_USER: change-me2
```

Environment variables have been set correctly, but why hasn't the value in the args section been updated to reflect the environment variables?

I expect to get the same values of environment variables in `environment` and `args` sections